# Application container [.Net]

Tags: .net, windows, sandbox, appcontainer

I have a question. Is there a build in way to make process isolation for Windows application? 
I know that in Windows8\2012 there is WWAHost process that works as Application container for Metro application. But will it work for non Metro applications?
Or maybe there is another way?

I just want to execute application that will have own file\registry\WinAPI access, that won't affect other applications

Comment: No, you'll never get WWAHost working.  Use the .NET way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, actually we use AppDomains for sandboxing, but it caused some issues with other assemblies that we used. Ideally would be great, if we can run execute code with assemblies in Windows sandbox, so code can use Registry\Network\IO\WinApi, but it would be restricted, and won't affected other applications.